# How to get reference of Activity object from onRegistered() method in GCMBaseIntentService

Tags: android, service, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently using Google GCM push notification services in android. I have completed the PUSH and it is working great. Now I have to send my server some device details on successful registration to Google server. So Now I need a Activity object reference.

```
   protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_registered));           
        registerToMyServer(context, registrationId); //initiate a rest call
        // the context above returns application context not the activity context
    }

   public void registerToMyServer(Activity activity, String rid){
         //handing REST
   }
```

Can anyone help me in this. How can we manage to get a Activity reference from onRegistered() method from GCMBaseIntentService subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need an reference to a Activity?. If you do not need users interaction you do not need Activity.

> Now I have to send my server some device details on successful
>   registration...

This can be done at your current onRegistered method (but of course you should make a class that handles this).

Another thing you must understand is GCMBaseIntentService is a Service... hence when you completed your registration ,your activity might or might not exist. Therefore, please reconsider the design.

You do not need Activity reference to get phone details   Activity extends from Context, hence you can get it from Context as provided.

```
 ↳  android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
```

For more information, look at the samples given in:
C:\Users\USERNAME\android-sdks\extras\google\gcm\samples\gcm-demo-client\src\com\google\android\gcm\demo\app\
GCMIntentService.java  AND  ServerUtilities.java

Comment: your above point "This can be done at your current onRegistered method (but of course you should make a class that handles this)". But how?

Comment: Are you trying to HttpPost data to your server?

Comment: Yes I need to post data to server. Also, I need to attach the device details like screen size etc to server. To get device details I need the activity reference.

Comment: If you found this helpful and solve your problem, you can mark this as answer.

Comment: Have you Looked at the gcm examople?